# Java program given string to replace character in the place of another character

Tags: java

Example `String str ="Java";` get output as "jXavXa".

hint: replace every 'a' with 'Xa'. and another one in same pgrm replace only last occurrence of 'e' to 'Xa'

example: I/p = "experience" and o/p= "experiencXe" .

Comment: Have a browse through the Javadoc for the String class.  I'm sure you'll find something suitable.

Comment: Is Javadoc is website? Or study material?

Comment: Its the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Also googling something like "java string replace by pattern" will yield good results.

Comment: Start at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

For the first case you can use a simple replace call:

```
str = str.replace("a","Xa");
```

For the case of replacing last occurrence, i don't think theres a direct way to do it, but you can implement your own using lastIndexOf(string) to find where in the string you will replace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
if you want to replace last occurence of 'e' to 'Xa'.

```
String result = str.replaceAll("a|e$", "Xa");
```

Or if you want to replace last occurrence of 'e' to 'Xe'.

```
String result = str.replaceAll("(a|e$)", "X$1");
```